# How to create a chrome extension code to extract ads from a webpage and save it as an html file?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, banner-ads

I am developing a chrome extension for fetching ads from a web page. What I am trying to do is that:

1. My extension should look for HTML5 banner ads from the opened web page.
2. It should detach the ad code and save it to my computer as an html file.
3. The html file created should not depend on an external JS or CSS file. It means when it gets detached, the CSS or JS code attached to it should be detached and saved as a part of the html page (not a hyper link).

I was wondering if there are any existing libraries or open source plugins that do that. If not, can anyone point me in the right direction where to begin?

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with problems, it looks like you didn't try anything, no research was done what so ever, you should edit your question with a problem we could actually help and not to look like you asking us to do the work for you.

Comment: I would suggest that you read the [Chrome extension architecture overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch). It has overall architecture information which should help your understanding of how things are generally done/organized.

Answer (score -2):

This won't directly pick out banner ads for you, you'll need to do that yourself, but all the functionality you're hoping for is available using [content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).